# combobox items to the where clause

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to get all the datas from the combobox items, the items in the combobox are dates which will be coming from users also,

this is for the payroll, so when the user input an employee ID all of the log datas or the attendance dates will appear then he can add it to the combobox, so the combo box will have items in date format which will be multiple,

Now first is that i need to get all the datas from this combobox,

```
string query = 
    "SELECT SUM(MinuteWorked)/60 AS 'workhours' FROM payroll.attendance WHERE  Date='"+
    cmbDates.Items+"' AND EmployeeID='" + 
    lblEmpID.Text + "'";
```

I need to compare it and check all the Date in data base that matches the items from the combo box.

Comment: Side-note: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Now would be a good time to learn about parameterized queries.

Comment: You can't directly use Items. You need to convert to text in the form of  an `IN (value1, value2, value3)`, where each `value` is an item in the combobox. For that you need code in a loop. And don't directly concatenate user input into SQL; as @Blorgbeard has said, it leaves you very vulnerable to SQL injection. (Building a dynamic WHERE..IN clause from a combobox is safe if you have control over the items in the combobox and are not allowing the user to enter items into it.)